# slides hidden on page load, but becomes visible after clicking on dots

Tags: javascript

It seems there is some error in javascript, please help.
Slides are not visible at page load, but appears o click of dot.

```
var slideIndex = 1;
    showSlides(slideIndex);

    function plusSlides(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex += n);
    }

    function currentSlide(n) {
        showSlides(slideIndex = n);
    }

    function showSlides(n) {
        var i;
        var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
        var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
        if (n > slides.length) {
            slideIndex = 1
        }
        if (n < 1) {
            slideIndex = slides.length
        }
        for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
            slides[i].style.display = "none";
        }
        for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
            dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
        dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " active";
    }
```

Comment: Please, provide your HTML too

Answer (score 1):

You are defining all the functions for sliding but it doesn't look like you are calling any of them until a click.  Try adding 
`showSlides()` below your code.

Answer (score 0):

Asif Vk could you demonstrate in JSFiddle?